# Why is this Node script double-counting

Tags: javascript, node.js

When I run this code:

```
var os = require('os')
var http = require('http')

var userCount = 0;

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
  userCount++;
  response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
  response.write('Hi there! I\'m being served from ' + os.hostname() + ': ' + userCount + ' visits\n');
  response.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

with `npm start` it outputs:

```
Hi there! I'm being served from my-host: 1 visits
```

Then:

```
Hi there! I'm being served from my-host: 3 visits
Hi there! I'm being served from my-host: 5 visits
```

Any idea why? And how to make it increment like this 1,2,3,4, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your browser sends a separate request to retrieve a favicon behind the scene.

Just do:

```
var os = require('os')
var http = require('http')

var userCount = 0;

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    if (request.url != '/favicon.ico') {
        userCount++;
        response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });
        response.write('Hi there! I\'m being served from ' + os.hostname() + ': ' + userCount + ' visits\n');
        response.end();
    }
}).listen(3000);
```